# Preview all visible layers in GIMP

Tags: gimp, layers

I am attempting to wrap an image around a tilted cylinder using the Curve Bend tool, however, due to perspective this is proving difficult. The main issue is that I cannot see the cylinder in the preview window as it is in a different layer. Is there any way to see all visible layers in the preview window?

best regards, Mathias

Comment: Likely much better results with `Filers>Map>Map object` and use map to `Cylinder`.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the "map object" distortion filter instead? The Curve Bend tool, in my experience, basically changes the image within the image plane rather than adding perspective. If you go to the Filters>Map>Map Object, you can select cylinder as the shape around which to wrap the image.

Here's an image changed with Curve Bend:
[image]

And here's an image with Map Object (you can deselect the light, if you want):

[image]

Comment: Hi David, thanks for your answer. While useful, we typically look for longer answers. Would you be so kind as to [edit] your answer and add some more info on how this filter might help the questioner with their issue?

Comment: Thanks for the guidance! I[ve added explanation and examples to try to make the point much clearer.